# QGIS isolines from points and lines

Tags: qgis, dem, contour

I'm getting started with QGIS and I want to use survey data to generate isolines. Contour plugin works well except when surveyed area has linear details (say, a road) that are elevated relative to the surrounding terrain.

One way to deal with this is to insert points at regular interval (say 20 cm) between points with same code (top of the slope, bottom of the slope).

What is the proper way of dealing with this in QGIS? Is there any plug-in that also uses the concept of "line" along with that of a "point" to generate DTM/contours?

Edit: by "line" here I actually mean a line segment with the two end-points having 3D coordinates (acad style).

Alternatively, what is the easiest way of inserting intermediate points in the fashion described above?